# How to calculate object keypoint similarity

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pose-estimation

I am trying to compute Object Keypoint similarity to evaluate the keypoint detection of an algorithm. below is code I've written based on what I've found and understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61461803/5015683)

[image: oks formula]

```
def oks(gt, preds, threshold, v, gt_area):
    ious = np.zeros((len(preds), len(gt)))
    sigmas = np.array([.26, .25, .25, .35, .35, .79, .79, .72, .72, .62,.62, 1.07, 1.07, .87, .87, .89, .89])/10.0
    vars = (sigmas*2)**2
    k = len(sigmas)

    xg = gt[:, 0]; yg = gt[:, 1]
    xp = preds[:, 0]; yp = preds[:, 1]
    vg = v + 1 # add one to visibility tags
    k1 = np.count_nonzero(vg > 0)
    dx = np.subtract(xg, xp)
    dy = np.subtract(yg, yp)

    e = (dx**2+dy**2)/vars/(gt_area+np.spacing(1))/2
    if threshold is not None:
        ind = list(vg > threshold)
        e = e[ind]
    ious = np.sum(np.exp(-e))/(1.5*e.shape[0]) if len(e) != 0 else 0
    return ious
```

where,

`gt, preds` are 17x2 NumPy arrays containing 17 (x, y) coordinates of human pose for ground truth and prediction from the machine learning model respectively.

`threshold` = 0.5(coco dataset uses 0.5 as a soft threshold),

`v` = visibility of ground truth keypoints(17x1 NumPy array) with values 0 = visible and 1 = occluded( thus we do vg=v+1 to comply with oks formula)

`gt_area` = area of the bounding box for ground truth person.

I was under the impression that oks is supposed to yield a value for each of the keypoints but the above code leads to a single value for all the keypoints combined. Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

As defined on the [COCO Dataset Website - Evaluate section](https://cocodataset.org/#keypoints-eval):

> For each **object**, ground truth keypoints have the form [x1,y1,v1,...,xk,yk,vk], where x,y are the keypoint locations and v is a visibility flag defined as v=0: not labeled, v=1: labeled but not visible, and v=2: labeled and visible.

The OKS metric is not computed per keypoint, it is a relative metric computed for each sample *(body in the case of Human Pose Estimation)*.

[image: Object Keypoint Similarity metric]

On OKS the sum is done over all sample's keypoints and the visibility flag is used as a dirac *(i.e if the keypoint is labeled `\delta(v_i > 0)` is 1 else 0 without consideration of occluded keypoints)*

```py
import numpy as np


def oks(y_true, y_pred, visibility):
    # You might want to set these global constant
    # outside the function scope
    KAPPA = np.array([1] * len(y_true))
    # The object scale
    # You might need a dynamic value for the object scale
    SCALE = 1.0

    # Compute the L2/Euclidean Distance
    distances = np.linalg.norm(y_pred - y_true, axis=-1)
    # Compute the exponential part of the equation
    exp_vector = np.exp(-(distances**2) / (2 * (SCALE**2) * (KAPPA**2)))
    # The numerator expression
    numerator = np.dot(exp_vector, visibility.astype(bool).astype(int))
    # The denominator expression
    denominator = np.sum(visibility.astype(bool).astype(int))
    return numerator / denominator


if __name__ == "__main__":
    IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL = 50
    gt = (np.random.random((17, 2)) * IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL).astype(int)
    pred = (np.random.random((17, 2)) * IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL).astype(int)
    visibility = (np.random.random((17, 1)) * 3).astype(int)

    # On this example the value will not be correct
    # since you need to calibrate KAPPA and SCALE
    print("OKS", oks(gt, pred, visibility))
```

```js
import numpy as np


def oks(y_true, y_pred, visibility):
    # You might want to set these global constant
    # outside the function scope
    KAPPA = np.array([1] * len(y_true))
    # The object scale
    # You might need a dynamic value for the object scale
    SCALE = 1.0

    # Compute the L2/Euclidean Distance
    distances = np.linalg.norm(y_pred - y_true, axis=-1)
    # Compute the exponential part of the equation
    exp_vector = np.exp(-(distances**2) / (2 * (SCALE**2) * (KAPPA**2)))
    # The numerator expression
    numerator = np.dot(exp_vector, visibility.astype(bool).astype(int))
    # The denominator expression
    denominator = np.sum(visibility.astype(bool).astype(int))
    return numerator / denominator


if __name__ == "__main__":
    IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL = 50
    gt = (np.random.random((17, 2)) * IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL).astype(int)
    pred = (np.random.random((17, 2)) * IMAGE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL).astype(int)
    visibility = (np.random.random((17, 1)) * 3).astype(int)

    # On this example the value will not be correct
    # since you need to calibrate KAPPA and SCALE
    print("OKS", oks(gt, pred, visibility))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```